# General formula for harmonic sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, means

Arithmetic sequence and arithmetic mean are correlated like that
$$
a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n+1}}{2}
$$
So all elements of arithmetic sequence $a_n=a+(n-1)r$ are satisfy that.
$$
\frac{a+(n-2)r+a+nr}{2}=a+(n-1)r
$$
The same with geometric sequence
$$
a_n=\sqrt{a_{n-1}a_{n+1}}
$$
for $a_n=aq^{n-1}$ we have
$$
\sqrt{aq^{n-2}aq^n}=\sqrt{a^2q^{2(n-1)}}=aq^{n-1}
$$
But what with harmonic sequence? $a_n=\frac{1}{a+(n-1)r}$
It doesn't satisfy harmonic mean.
$$
\frac{2}{\frac{1}{a+(n-1)r}+\frac{1}{a+(n+1)r}}=\frac{\left(a+(n-1)r\right)\left(a+(n+1)r\right)}{a+nr}\not=\frac{1}{a+nr}
$$

How looks like the sequence which satisfy harmonic sequence?

For arithmetic sequence I can start like that
$$
a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n+1}}{2}\Rightarrow 2a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n+1}\Rightarrow a_n-a_{n-1}=a_{n+1}-a_n
$$
So difference should be constant. We can start from any number $a$ and add some multiply of another number $r$. $a_n=a+nr$. 
For geometric mean:
$$
a_n=\sqrt{a_{n-1}a_{n+1}}\Rightarrow a_n^2=a_{n-1}a_{n+1}\Rightarrow \frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
$$
So quotient should be constant. $a_n=aq^n$.
For harmonic mean
$$
a_n=\frac{2}{\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}+\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}}\Rightarrow a_n=\frac{2a_{n-1}a_{n+1}}{a_{n-1}+a_{n+1}}
$$
It isn't so nice. I found this form (maybe is useful)
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n-1}}=\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{a_n-a_{n-1}}
$$
What kind of method should I use to find this sequence?

Comment: A sequence $(a_n)$ is harmonic if and only if the sequence $(1/a_n)$ is arithmetic hence you should reach the condition that, for every $n\geqslant1$, $$a_n=\frac1{\frac1{a_1}+(n-1)r}=\frac{a_1}{1+(n-1)ra_1}.$$ Using $b=\frac1{a_1}-r$, one sees that an equivalent formula is $$a_n=\frac{1}{b+nr}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just defining $a_n$ in terms of $a_{n+1}$ and $a_{n-1}$ and trying to expand the $a_{n+1},a_{n-1}$ function, I would recommend trying to isolate $a_{n+1}$

Arithmetic:

$a_n = \frac{a_{n+1}+a_{n-1}}{2}$

$2*a_n = a_{n+1}+a_{n-1}$

$a_{n+1} = 2 * a_n - a_{n-1} = a_n + (a_n - a_{n-1})$

Geometric:

$a_n = √(a_{n+1}a_{n-1})$

$(a_n)^2 = a_{n+1}a_{n-1}$

$a_{n+1} = \frac{(a_n)^2}{a_{n-1}} = a_n * \frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}$

Harmonic:

$a_n = \frac{2}{\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}+\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}}$

$\frac{2}{a_n} = \frac{1}{a_{n+1}}+\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}$

$\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{2}{a_n}-\frac{1}{a_{a-1}} = \frac{1}{a_n}+(\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{1}{a_{a-1}})$

Do you know what to do next?